# Мультиселект с полем поиска в выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Предмет моего вопроса - вот такой селект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В развернутом виде он выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, проблема в том, что все плагины для селектов которые я находил имеют функционал, недостаточный для реализации подобной формы. Где есть мультиселект отсутствует поле поиска в выпадающем списке и наоборот.

Подскажите, может подобный плагин все же существует или, например, реально ли воспользоваться плагином select2, где есть оба варианта по отдельности (мультиселект и селект с инпутом для поиска в выпадающем списке), для реализации формы в соответствии с дизайном?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую [select2](https://select2.github.io/) - да, он вам подойдет:

1. При инициализации он сам смотрит, к какому селекту привязывается - множественному или одиночному, как-либо уточнять эту часть в параметрах не нужно;
2. Поле поиска удобно показывать за счет параметра `minimumResultsForSearch: 10` - это значит, что при менее чем 10 вариантах - поля не будет, а начиная с 10 - будет.
3. Чекбоксы в селекте реализуются в два этапа. (1) Параметром `closeOnSelect: false` указываем, что при клике по какому-либо пункту - селект закрывать не нужно. И (2) за счет стилей псевдоэлемента `::before` дополняем пункты селекта чекбоксами.

Стили для чекбоксов можно задать так:

```
.select2-results__option {
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.select2-results__option::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]::before {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Виталий, а как быть с чекбоксами? Надеюсь я что-то упустил, потому что не вижу возможности в селект2 сделать такой селект с чекбоксами..

Comment: Дополнил ответ информацией по чекбоксам.

Comment: Виталий, из первого пункта вашего комментария следует (если я вас правильно понял), что указывать параметр multiple в селекте не следует. Сделал все согласно вашим инструкциям, появилось три проблемы, очень жду вашего совета:
1) Поле поиска не появилось
2) При выборе нескольких пунктов из выпадающего списка высота инпута селекта увеличивается
3) Отсутствует иконка "caret", которая переворачивается при раскрытии списка (можно ли ее подключить каким-то образом? сам в документации плагина не нашел такую возможность, пилить её самому, с учетом того что селекты имеют фон, крайне не хотелось бы)

Comment: здесь все более наглядно: http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/YGpdBp

Comment: 1) Поле поиска у select2 совмещено с полем выбранных тегов, это вряд ли можно изменить; 2) Да, высота неизбежно будет увеличиваться, если теги перестают помещаться в одну строку - на ваших скриншотах два тега и они помещаются, но если бы там было 3-4 тега - что должно происходить по вашему дизайну в таком случае? 3) Да, при multiple-выборе иконка caret отсутствует, потому что само поле здесь является инпутом для ввода текста, а не селектом.

Comment: 1) Так ведь изначально главным вопросом в моем топике была возможность совмещения поля поиска в выпадающем окне с мультиселектом... Видимо вы меня не до конца поняли(
2, 3) Остальные вопросы теряют актуальность в связи с ответом на первый..

Comment: Если подходить к вопросу так - то да, select2 для такого не подойдет. И боюсь, что другие развитые js-селекты - тоже. Поле выбора тегов вместо multiple-селекта - уже несколько лет как устоявшаяся форма селекта. Обычно в таких случаях я рекомендую обращаться к дизайнерам с просьбой создавать дизайн в соответствии с современными реалиями в верстке.

Comment: Попробую убедить в этом и заказчика, спасибо за время, потраченное на помощь)